# Why are sub-subsections of the Irish constitution marked with the degree symbol?

Tags: typography, citation, hiberno-english

[The accepted legal practice](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=0SQdDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16&dq=%22%C2%B0%22%20irish%20constitution%20degree%20symbol&source=bl&ots=UPHGNvV_9l&sig=ACfU3U2roHyXXEuzyCa9FyK9l1ByqFhTvQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjxl5n2mobpAhXoQhUIHRVgAu0Q6AEwCnoECBMQAQ#v=onepage&q=degree%20symbol&f=false) when referring to sub-subsections of the Irish constitution is to use the degree symbol to mark sub-subsections.  For example, Art 40.3.3°.  This convention is not used for Irish statutes, or indeed, as far as I can see, for any other text in English or, for that matter Irish (which has its own ordinal markers).  The convention is to use the degree symbol rather than other similar diacritics.

What are the origins of this practice and why does it seem to apply to **only** the Irish constitution and **only** to sub-subsections? What indication is intended to be conveyed by the degree symbol that is not carried by the decimal system of denoting section  numbering?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks for the reason a particular style choice is favoured by OSCOLA Ireland, essentially a style guide recommended / mandated for use with a particular subsection of legalese. _Not_ general English usage.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_symbol) mentions 1° for *primo* (in the first place), 2° for *secundo* (in the second place), etc, in the 18th century. Which might be an influence. Not convinced this is on topic; is there another place for typographical questions?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks for the reason a particular style choice is favoured by OSCOLA Ireland, essentially a style guide recommended / mandated for use with a particular subsection of legalese. Not general English usage.